# How can I use $http get response data for $http post request - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working on one project(AngularJS+PHP) where I use one database for users login (params about users/clients and their databases) and the other database for user/client(every user has own database).
When I sign in, I want to connect to correct database .I'm login in successfully with some client account, catch db parameters for client database, but when I need to connect to corresponding client database it's not working.
I use service:

```
app.factory('loginService', function ($http, $location, sessionService) {
return{
   .........................
      fetchuser: function () {
              var usr = $http.get('model/fetch.php');
             return usr;
            },
      fetchdbdata: function (dbdata) {
              var usrdb = $http.post('model/fetchDB_data.php', dbdata);
              return usrdb;
           }
       }
    .........................
});
```

and corresponding controller:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'loginService', '$location',     
    function ($scope, loginService, $location) {
       var dbdata;     
       var userrequest = loginService.fetchuser();
       userrequest.then(function (response) {
           //take users data, database params 
           $scope.usr = response.data[0];        

           //in console  dbdata return correct object
           dbdata = {
                 host_name: $scope.usr.host_name,
                 database_name: $scope.usr.database_name,
                 user_db: $scope.usr.user_db,
                 password_db: $scope.usr.password_db
                };      
            console.log(dbdata);
            /* ***************************************
               if i use manually data like:
            dbdata = {
                host_name: "mysql333****",
                database_name: "da*******",
                user_db: "uc******",
                password_db: "^r******"
               };
            console.log(dbdata);
              it works, and in console bellow return correct object and 
              result. 
              I don't understand why.
            *******************************************/       
           var userrequestdb = loginService.fetchdbdata(dbdata); 
           userrequestdb.then(function (response) {               
               $scope.usrdb = response.data[0];
               console.log($scope.usrdb);  //in console return E - nothing
           });
       });
    }
]);
```

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Where's your PHP code? How do you know the problem is front-end and not backend? What error message? Where's the evidence that it's not working? Show us the actual output from your console that proves the dbdata object is the same.

Comment: Here are some additions. First I think that backend is ok because everything works for dbdata object from comments. Here is pictures of console for that case https://www.dropbox.com/s/4njse5rjoum13vm/secondCase.JPG?dl=0 , and pictures when run code for dbdata above comments https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7gd1sg0rd0l7q6/firstCase.JPG?dl=0

Comment: So what's the problem? Seems from your screenshot of the console that you're getting a response from the backend.

Comment: Yes, it works when I manually insert data for dbdata object(for this one in comments in code), but this dbdata object above comments makes problem for unknown reason. It looks like the both object dbdata are same, but response object(for $http.post) for this case in console is "E"(second picture link). I don't know why happens it. I need that first(dynamically) solution for monitoring more than one databese. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Then why don't you show the console when you get the error instead of for when it works?

Comment: Sorry, probably my explanation is a bit confusing. I'll try again explain my problem. I add two lines for console.log in code. For this code that is set in my post, console output is in second picture (second link in my first answer to you). Response object for $http.post in that case is "E"(program don't work). When I change the first dbdate object with this one from the comment(with values "mysql333****", .....) response is good and that is on first picture link(program works in that case).

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The database names are different:
In the one that's not working it is "consultech_17"
In the one that is working it is "consultech_rs_db_16"